# Do Reinstalling Apache 2 Unlinks the Domain?

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4

I've a dedicated server. I reinstalled apache on it by running the following commands:-

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

And now when I access the domain name it says:

```
Not Found
The requeted URL / was not found on this server.
```

Also it was parallel's plesk control panel and now it is parallel's power panel. Did all this happen because of the commands I ran or some other person changed it?

Comment: This question is off topic because of Plesk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get purge apache2` removes :

- `Apache2` packets
- all dependencies
- **all configuration files**

You have to reconfigure Apache, or restore config files from backups.

Comment: Are there any auto backups? Because I don't think so that I have a backup.

Comment: No auto backups until you setup them. `apt-get remove` keeps config files